# If $\,\mathbf{v}(x, y, z)=e^{yx}(y\mathbf{i}+x\mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k})\,$ is there $\,f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R\,$ s.t. $\,\mathbf{v}=\nabla f$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A question asked me to calculate $\nabla \times \mathbf{v}$ where $\,\mathbf{v}(x, y, z) = e^{yx}\left(y\mathbf{i}+x\mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k}\right),\,$ which I've found to be $\nabla \times \mathbf{v} = xze^{yx}\mathbf{i}-yz e^{yx}\mathbf{j}$. It further asked: does there exist a function $f$: $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbf{v} =  \nabla f$?

I think it may have to do with the third coordinate being $0$ but I couldn't come up with an answer.

Comment: what is $\nabla \times \nabla f$ for a general $f$? Calculate it and you find your answer :)

Comment: @Hamed $\displaystyle \nabla \times \nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial z}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z \partial y}\right)\mathbf{i}+
\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z \partial x}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial z}\right)\mathbf{j}+
\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}-\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}\right)\mathbf{k} = \vec{0}.$ Since $\nabla \times \mathbf{v} = xze^{yx}\mathbf{i}-yz e^{yx}\mathbf{j} \ne \vec{0}$, there does not exist a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\mathbf{v} = \nabla f.$

Comment: Please see [vector calculus identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Curl_of_the_gradient) related to [irrotational vector fileds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Irrotational_vector_fields).

Comment: That's exactly it ;)

Comment: @Hamed Many thanks! :)